# Application of Bayes Theorem

Tags: probability

Frank steps out from his afternoon teatime to take a phone call and leaves his tea on the table. While he is taking the call, his father walks by his tea with $P(I) =  0.15$  , his mother with $P(J) = 0.3$  , his brother with $P(K) = 0.5$  and his sister with $P(L) = 0.05$.

When Frank comes back to his tea, he finds it filled with salt. Frank believes that whenever his father walks by his tea, he has a probability of $0.05$  to put salt in it, when his mother walks by, a probability $0.03$  , when his brother walks by, a probability $0.01$  and when his sister walks by, a probability $0.05$.

I'm trying to find the conditional probabilities $P(I|S), \,  P(J|S), \, P(K|S), \,P(L|S)$.

So, from my interpretation, it appears that walking by is a mutually exclusive event; only one of them could have walked by. I'm also given all of the reversed conditional probabilities for the four events, so Bayes' Theorem seems like the obvious tool to select.

However, my issue is in finding $P(S|I'), \,  P(S|J'), \, P(S|K'), \,P(S|L')$.

It seems valid that, by extending the apparent mutually exclusive nature of the events, to believe that $P(S|I')$  , for example, is just $P(S|J)+P(S|K)+P(S|L)$  , leading me to believe that it was Frank's mother who placed the salt in his tea.

Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: What a strange family Frank has!

Comment: @Deepak Hahahaha, I come up with weird scenarios sometimes. Good for learning though.

Comment: I have a question... How do you know walking by is a mutually exclusive event? Though $P(I)+P(J)+P(K)+P(L)=1$, it doesn't necessarily mean they are mutually exclusive. They can be independent events still.

Comment: @Asydot Well, my reasoning was, if the sample space $S = {I, J, K, L}$ and by Kolmogorov $P(\bigcup_{i=1}^nE_i) = \sum_{i=1}^nP(E_i) = 1$, then it would seem reasonable to assume that was the case. However, you're right, it's an assumption.

Comment: @genap I'm surprised that no others concerning about this question. I think the question itself is not well-defined. The only two assumption make the question possible to be solved are that they are 1)mutually exclusive or 2)mutually independent. Personally I prefer to take latter. However, neither of them has sufficient reason - maybe this is decided by how long will Frank speak. (There is a good idea to reject my preference : If, during Frank talking, two or more families walk by, the possibility for them to put salt may not be independent - usually.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bayes' Theorem is the right tool, but there is no need to consider the individual complementary probabilities.

Draw a tree diagram, I find it very useful.

From the apex, you have four branches, each representing the walk-by events $I,J,K,L$ with respective probabilities $p(I), p(J), p(K), p(L)$.

From each of those nodes, you can branch into $S$ (salt added) and $S'$ (no salt added). The "salt added" branches would have conditional probabilities of $p(S|I), p(S|J), p(S|K), p(S|L)$ respectively. You're only concerned with these branches since you already know the salt has been added.

So if you now want to find the individual probabilities for each family member having done it, you apply BT four times.

For the father:

$$P(I|S) = \frac{p(S|I)\cdot p(I)}{p(S|I)\cdot p(I) + p(S|J)\cdot p(J) + p(S|K)\cdot p(K) + p(S|L)\cdot p(L)}$$

You can construct analogous formulae for the other family members. Note that the denominator remains the same, so calculate that first.

I get:

$p(I|S) = 31.25\% \ (=\frac{5}{16}), \\ p(J|S) = 37.5\%\ (=\frac{3}{8}), \\ p(K|S) = 20.8\overline{3}\%\ (=\frac{5}{24}), \\ p(L|S) = 10.41\overline{6}\%\ (=\frac{5}{48})$

Comment: Not sure why I forgot the ol' "Probability Tree" representation...worked it over, got the same answers as you. Thanks for the help!